# Azure DevOps : Install an agent in a Neo4j VM created on Azure

Tags: neo4j, azure-devops

I have an article recommendation project in Python.

I started a Pipeline (Build) in Azure Devops. I did the first steps of my project: 1) Scrape data 2) Clean data

The next step is inserting the data in a Neo4j database. But I don't know how to work with this database in Azure DevOps.

I tought about using a Neo4j VM in this step but I don't know if I have to install an agent on the VM or do something else (docker image ?).

What can I do ?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not that familiar with neo4j, can you share some details about how you insert the data into database locally? Can it be done with command-line?

Comment: Here is how I do to insert the data locally:
1. I start Neo4j Desktop and I launch my database
2. In my jupyter notebook, I connect to the database with python code (and a python driver for Neo4j)
3. I use Cypher requests and I iterate through a dataframe to select column I want to insert into nodes

If you need more details about how to insert data into neo4j locally don't hesitate to tell me.

I don't know if it is possible with command line but I saw this video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y82cDPxSAKY&ab_channel=TechnologyGlobe

Comment: We can't access GUI during auzre devops pipeline run, it's not like what we can do locally. So the recommended way is to 1.migrate local operations into command-line script 2. move the command-line into cloud CMD task/PS task and test/fix the random issue

Comment: Thank you @lance Li-MSFT I'm going to try it

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT How do I do 2. move the command-line into cloud CMD task/PS ?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT maybe I can do this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/neo4j

Comment: In my opinion, [this way](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/cloud-deployments/neo4j-azure/automation-azure/) is the closest one. See: Automate Neo4j deployment when you want to integrate Neo4j into your CI/CD pipeline to be able to create/destroy instances temporarily, or to spin up a sample instance.

Answer (score 0):

1.Azure Devops supports running pipelines in [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install). Thus we can run the jobs/tasks in our local machine with local environment.

2.Also, you can use [docker task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops) with DockerFile to do actions with docker. Your steps about how to insert data into `neo4j` database should be written in DockerFile. (In addition: [Container jobs for Yaml pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops) can even support directly running tasks in container)

However, the **core point** is that whether `neo4j` has feature of inserting data in database via Command-line or Powershell script. I'm not enperienced at neo4j database, I did some searching and only find this command [neo4j-admin import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/).

Whether you can insert data in azure devops pipeline depend on whether neo4j supports command-line inserting. If neo4j supports command-line inserting, both self-hosted agents or docker can be suitable for you.

Comment: Thank you @Lance Li-MFST, I'm going to try it.